# How to use scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain in Spark, just like calling the eval in Perl

Tags: scala, apache-spark, eval, interpreter

I am trying to dinamically interpret code given as a String in Spark, just like calling the eval in Perl language. However, I got problem when running the program. Really appreciate for your help.

**Requirement:**

The requirement is to make the spark processing chain configurable. For example, customer could set the processing steps in configuration file as below. Steps:

> ```
> 1) textFile("files///<file_full_path>") 
> 2) flatMap(line => line.split(" ")) 
> 3) map(word => (word, 1)) 
> 4) reduceByKey(_ + _) 
> 5) foreach(println)
> ```

All above steps are defined in a configuration file.
Then, the spark driver will load the configuration file and make the processing steps as a string, such as:

> ```
> val processFlow = 
> """
> sc.textFile("file:///input.txt").flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _).foreach(println)
> """
> ```

Then, Spark will execute the piece of code defined in above variable processFlow.

**Here is my Spark source code:**

It is from word count sample, I just make the RDD methods invoked by interpreter as a string.

> ```
> import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
> import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
> import scala.collection.mutable.{Map, ArraySeq}
> import scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerSettings
> import scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain
> class TestMain {
>   def exec(): Unit = {
>     val out = System.out
>     val flusher = new java.io.PrintWriter(out)
>     val interpreter = {
>       val settings = new GenericRunnerSettings( println _ )
>       settings.usejavacp.value = true
>       new IMain(settings, flusher)
>     }
>     val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TestMain")
>     val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
>     val methodChain =
>       """
>       val textFile = sc.textFile("file:///input.txt")
>       textFile.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _).foreach(println)
>       """
>     interpreter.bind("sc", sc);
>     val resultFlag = interpreter.interpret(methodChain)
>   }
> }
> object TestMain {
>   def main(args: Array[String]) {
>     val testMain = new TestMain()
>     testMain.exec()
>     System.exit(0)
>   }
> }
> ```

**Problem:**

However, I got an error when running above Spark code (master=local), logs as below.

> ```
> sc: org.apache.spark.SparkContext = org.apache.spark.SparkContext@7d87addd
> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: $anonfun$1
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>         at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
>         at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:68)
>         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1612)
>         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
>         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
>         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
>         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
>         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
>         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
>         at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:76)
>         at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:115)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
>         at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Driver stacktrace:
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
>         at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>         at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
>         at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
>         at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1843)
>         at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1856)
>         at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1869)
>         at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1940)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:927)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:926)
>         at .<init>(<console>:12)
>         at .<clinit>(<console>)
>         at .<init>(<console>:7)
>         at .<clinit>(<console>)
>         at $print(<console>)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>         at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:734)
>         at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:983)
>         at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:573)
>         at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:604)
>         at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:568)
>         at com.tr.ecp.test.TestMain.exec(TestMain.scala:44)
>         at com.tr.ecp.test.TestMain$.main(TestMain.scala:57)
>         at com.tr.ecp.test.TestMain.main(TestMain.scala)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: $anonfun$1
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>         at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
>         at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:68)
>         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1612)
>         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
>         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
>         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
>         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
>         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
>         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
>         at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:76)
>         at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:115)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
>         at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> resultFlag = Error, returnObj = None
> ```

Comment: Apache Zeppelin doing extractly this, writing code on a web page, and execute it. Perhaps you can have a look to Zeppelin and see how it solves the issue.

Comment: Hi Rockie, really appreciate for your information. I will look the Apache Zeppelin.

Comment: Hi, I am having similar requirement to be implemented. Have you solved it? May i know which `scala` and `Spark` versions you used, since i cannot resolve dependencies when i tried to do the same.

Comment: Spark Shell handle it by [ExecutorClassLoader.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/repl/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/repl/ExecutorClassLoader.scala)

Answer (score 1):

Checked with Apache Zeppelin implementation. Here is the [code snippet](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/master/spark/src/main/java/org/apache/zeppelin/spark/SparkInterpreter.java#L759) which used to interpret the input.

It basic uses org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop with some code take care of dependency.

```
public InterpreterResult interpretInput(String[] lines, InterpreterContext context) {
  SparkEnv.set(env);

  // add print("") to make sure not finishing with comment
  // see https://github.com/NFLabs/zeppelin/issues/151
  String[] linesToRun = new String[lines.length + 1];
  for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    linesToRun[i] = lines[i];
  }
  linesToRun[lines.length] = "print(\"\")";

  Console.setOut(context.out);
  out.setInterpreterOutput(context.out);
  context.out.clear();
  Code r = null;
  String incomplete = "";
  boolean inComment = false;

  for (int l = 0; l < linesToRun.length; l++) {
    String s = linesToRun[l];
    // check if next line starts with "." (but not ".." or "./") it is treated as an invocation
    if (l + 1 < linesToRun.length) {
      String nextLine = linesToRun[l + 1].trim();
      boolean continuation = false;
      if (nextLine.isEmpty()
         || nextLine.startsWith("//")         // skip empty line or comment
         || nextLine.startsWith("}")
         || nextLine.startsWith("object")) {  // include "} object" for Scala companion object
        continuation = true;
      } else if (!inComment && nextLine.startsWith("/*")) {
        inComment = true;
        continuation = true;
      } else if (inComment && nextLine.lastIndexOf("*/") >= 0) {
        inComment = false;
        continuation = true;
      } else if (nextLine.length() > 1
              && nextLine.charAt(0) == '.'
              && nextLine.charAt(1) != '.'     // ".."
              && nextLine.charAt(1) != '/') {  // "./"
        continuation = true;
      } else if (inComment) {
        continuation = true;
      }
      if (continuation) {
        incomplete += s + "\n";
        continue;
      }
    }

    scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.Results.Result res = null;
    try {
      res = intp.interpret(incomplete + s);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      sc.clearJobGroup();
      out.setInterpreterOutput(null);
      logger.info("Interpreter exception", e);
      return new InterpreterResult(Code.ERROR, InterpreterUtils.getMostRelevantMessage(e));
    }

    r = getResultCode(res);

    if (r == Code.ERROR) {
      sc.clearJobGroup();
      out.setInterpreterOutput(null);
      return new InterpreterResult(r, "");
    } else if (r == Code.INCOMPLETE) {
      incomplete += s + "\n";
    } else {
      incomplete = "";
    }
  }

  if (r == Code.INCOMPLETE) {
    sc.clearJobGroup();
    out.setInterpreterOutput(null);
    return new InterpreterResult(r, "Incomplete expression");
  } else {
    sc.clearJobGroup();
    out.setInterpreterOutput(null);
    return new InterpreterResult(Code.SUCCESS);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, got it. I see the source code you post, it executes the code piece by "res = intp.interpret(incomplete + s);".